# OnClickListener of button in recyclerview acting on wrong view

Tags: android

I have a set of cardviews within a recyclerview. Each cardview contains a button. When the button is clicked, it is supposed to unhide a child of the cardview. However, it insists on unhiding the child with the same ID in the next cardview. I have no idea what's causing this or even what to search for. I'm also pretty sure I haven't explained any of this very well, so here's my adapter code (everything happens in here):

```
package in.kaluru.app.adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.databinding.DataBindingUtil;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import in.kaluru.app.BR;
import in.kaluru.app.R;
import in.kaluru.app.databinding.RowEntryBinding;
import in.kaluru.app.models.EntryModel;
import in.kaluru.app.views.MainActivityFragment;

/**
 * Created by ritvik on 22/4/16.
 */
public class EntryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EntryAdapter.EntryViewHolder>{
    public static List<EntryModel> mEntries;
    public View v;
    public Context mContext;
    public EntryAdapter(List<EntryModel> mEntries, Context mContext) {
        this.mEntries = mEntries;
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    public static class EntryViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private RowEntryBinding binding;

        public EntryViewHolder(View rowView) {
            super(rowView);
            binding = DataBindingUtil.bind(rowView);
        }

        public RowEntryBinding getBinding() {
            return binding;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public EntryViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, int type) {
        v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.row_entry, parent, false);

        v.findViewById(R.id.image_meta).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),
                        "This will open up a map showing nearby " +
                                "pictures with markers and have this one selected. Also still WIP.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        v.findViewById(R.id.fixed).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                v.findViewById(R.id.note_section).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });;

        v.findViewById(R.id.cancel_fixed).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                v.findViewById(R.id.note_section).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                v.findViewById(R.id.fixed).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
        EntryViewHolder holder = new EntryViewHolder(v);
        return holder;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(EntryViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final EntryModel entry = mEntries.get(position);

        v.findViewById(R.id.send_fixed).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final String uuid = entry.uuid;
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);
                String url = "https://kaluru.in/fixed";

                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {
                                entry.setFixed(true);
                                notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.d("Response", "That didn't work!");
                        Log.e("VolleyError", error.toString());
                    }
                }){
                    @Override
                    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
                        Map<String, String> mParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        mParams.put("uuid", uuid);
                        mParams.put("note", ((EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.note)).getText().toString());
                        return mParams;
                    }
                };
                queue.add(stringRequest);
            }
        });

        holder.getBinding().setVariable(BR.entry, entry);
        holder.getBinding().executePendingBindings();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mEntries.size();
    }
}
```

And here's a screenshot:
 [image]

The bit on the bottom where it says, "Note", "Send" and "Cancel" is actually supposed to be under the card which says, "Locality unavailable", which is the card which the button was in. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(EntryViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final EntryModel entry = mEntries.get(position);
        // the following is givving you a problem:
        v.findViewById(R.id.send_fixed).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

you are using a private member of your class `v` which if you are using the program in correct order, will hold your last view contents.

`onBindViewHolder` will give you a `holder` object which holds the current item of the `RecyclerView` so you need to make operations on your holder object instead of v. Probably something like this:

```
RowEntryBinding b = holder.getBinding();
//now perform operations on b object instead of v
```

Comment: `v` should be a local variable or `v = holder.itemView` in `onBindViewHolder()`

Comment: I see. I'm sorry I took so long to respond. I'll give it a go today, and if it works you have accepted answer. Thanks for your time.